# Working Example of Retention policies

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Can anyone explain me with a working example about retention policies?

Answer (score 3):

Check the below blog, She first explain the case why we need the retention then how to implement in the SHarepoint, I think this will solve your issue.

[Applying Document Retention in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2011/10/03/applying-document-retention-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: My main aim for asking this question is that i want to use something that is a replacement for a timerjob that periodically doing some task